# wealthy Switzerland

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I hired an American freelancer to correct my essay. I used the word "wealthy" to show the kind of thing the doctor wants to do. He is willing to leave his wealthy country. But the freelance deleted "wealthy". Is there anything wrong with "wealthy Switzerland"?

> A doctor trained in **wealthy Switzerland** might want to practice in
> Africa to help the most vulnerable.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 'wealthy Switzerland'. For balance, one might add 'impoverished' before 'Africa'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was likely removed because it seems out of place here—I wouldn't interpret the sentence in the way you intended it.
It seems like '*wealthy*' is used as a fixed adjective, like how one would say "mighty Carthage"; that is, more as a subjective qualifier than a descriptive adjective.

If you want to stress the sacrifice this doctor is willing to make, I suggest you rewrite the sentence to something more along the lines of the following:

> A doctor trained in Switzerland might want to give up their current quality of life to go practice in Africa to help the most vulnerable.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain their reason, so I can edit my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Joachim's answer, but I would like to expand on it slightly. There is nothing wrong with the phrase "wealthy Switzerland" per se, it is the juxtaposition with “trained in” that is confusing.

- Someone can be **trained in a location**: continent (e.g. Europe), country (e.g. England) or city (e.g. Cambridge).
- A person may be trained **in a specific field / area** (the/a/an): science(s) (e.g. medicine), the art(s) of, craft, or skill e.g. *they were fully trained in CPR*.
- A person can be trained in **a period of time**: hours, days, weeks, months or years e.g. *she hadn't trained in years*.

Therefore, to be *trained in wealthy Switzerland*  might be interpreted as a specialization, a course or field of study. Naturally, a native speaker would discard the notion but the phrase would still sound odd and out of place. The OP's original intention: a person trained in a wealthy state to then go and practice in a disadvantaged country would need to be rephrased.